# How to easily allow location input with back slashes in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am trying to manipulate folders and files in Windows using python. Unfortunately, my company's standard includes using back slashes instead of forward slashes in folder locations.

If I, or someone else copies over a location with back slashes in it, the code gets confused because it thinks it is an escape character. Is there any easy way to copy and paste the location (via input()) with back slashes, and then change the escape character to forward slashes easily?

Comment: Please give a [mcve]

Comment: You can try raw strings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this:

```
print raw_input().replace('\\','/')
```

Here you need to escape the backslash so Python could treat it as a single backslash.

> Input: `C:\\Windows\Users\ForceBru`
>   Output: `C://Windows/Users/ForceBru`

Comment: This helped a lot. Thanks.